# Override Jumbotron background color using the .bg- classes

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Currently I am using Bootstrap. For the themes I use the Bootswatch themes.
I noticed that the Jumbotron has in every theme the same ugly grey background. So I want to use the [`.bg-`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds) classes to change the color.

I also read:

**Dealing with specificity**

> Sometimes contextual background classes cannot be applied due to 
>   the specificity of another selector. In some cases, a sufficient 
>   workaround is to wrap your element's content in a  with the class.

So that is also what I have tried.

What I tried:

```
<div class="jumbotron bg-success">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>

<div class="bg-success">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this is not working because the `bg-` class is not overriding the jumbotron background color.

Example: http://www.bootply.com/yhvhdor7lr

### Edit

Related: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10202

Comment: Are you working with the source or the dist files?

Comment: @ilovecode I am working with http://bootstrapcdn.com

Comment: Ah right okay. You could just add a style rule of your own that says `.jumbotron { background-color: #YOURCOLOR }`, provided that is declared *after* the bootstrap CSS it will override

Comment: @ilovecode That is not what I am looking for, I could came up with that. Like I said, I am using bootswatch themes and I don't know what color the success boxes have... Like my question `with existing .bg- classes`

Comment: what if you bring in the bg-success into jumbotron div: <div class="jumbotron bg-success">

Comment: Open up the bootswatch theme file, `Ctrl` + `F`, find the .bg-success class, and copy the Hex Color Code

Comment: @Andi Then I get this: http://www.bootply.com/8PPQEx52WE

Comment: @ilovecode I am using a CDN...

Comment: here's the hex-code: #dff0d8

Comment: you could use firebug or chrome-dev-tools to show the css in your browser easily.

Comment: The theme is a CDN too? Okay, then create an element with just the bg-success class, inspect it with developer tools and find the background color..

Comment: You guys realy don't understand my question here. Please read before comment! A USER can choose out of 15+ themes. So an option to set a custom class is no way! I ask about the `.bg-` class!

Comment: if you add the bg- class IN the <div> as I told you and add the theme AFTER the boostrap.css the color will change properly with your existing class. Or you have to change the theme (and change to add it not from CDN) and add an !important rule

Comment: You could give every `.bg-class` an `!important` for the color. This would override the specifity. http://www.bootply.com/bGjsIDlMFZ

Comment: @Andi If I put the bg-class IN the <div> I get this: http://www.bootply.com/8PPQEx52WE Also it is impossible to change a script coming from a CDN.

Comment: dont put the div into the other div. take the class and put it in the div <div class="bg-class jumbotron">. But this will only work if your CDN gets an important rule. Btw you can download CSS files from CDNs and host them by yourself. Than you can edit them.

Comment: @Sebsemillia I know !important ovverrides. I use css for like 7 years now... But can you do this with files from a CDN?

Comment: @Andi Do you even know where a CDN is for?

Comment: If you want ANOTHER css you cant use a given one if this is not doing what you want!

Comment: Oh and btw, you could use javascript to add an important rule

Comment: Looking at the comments I conclude this is a issue in bootstrap..

Comment: @Bondye There are several solutions to overwrite the CDN loaded styles. You could use inline CSS or jQuery/javascript for example..

Comment: @Bondye But I guess if you are looking for a way to do it just with Bootstrap ready made classes, there is now way.

Answer (score 3):

the div wil take its background from the last rule on the css. For example, if in the stylesheet the `.jumbotron` class is in line 5 and `.bg-success` and both have `background-color` property, it will take the lastest line.

[try this bootply]{http://www.bootply.com/a123L6HQRi}. Move one class on the top of the other and press Run, see the results.

But you are using CDN and can't change the order of the rules or add `!important` to solve it. Maybe you should consider adding a custom stylesheet to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a late suggestion but it could help someone else.
I used the line of code below and it does it. Please note that jumbotron-blue-grey-200 could be any color like success, danger, etc.

`<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-material-blue-grey-200">
    <h1 class="text-primary">Your text here</h1>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

try change **bg** with **alert**

```
<div class="jumbotron alert-success">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
```